# Optimizing asymmetrically reweighted penalized least squares smoothing (from matlab to python)

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to apply the method for baselinining vibrational spectra, which is announced as an improvement over asymmetric and iterative re-weighted least-squares algorithms in the 2015 paper (doi:10.1039/c4an01061b), where the following matlab code was provided:

```
function z = baseline(y, lambda, ratio)
% Estimate baseline with arPLS in Matlab
N = length(y);
D = diff(speye(N), 2);
H = lambda*D'*D;
w = ones(N, 1);
while true
    W = spdiags(w, 0, N, N);
    % Cholesky decomposition
    C = chol(W + H);
    z = C \ (C' \ (w.*y) );
    d = y - z;
    % make d-, and get w^t with m and s
    dn = d(d<0);
    m = mean(d);
    s = std(d);
    wt = 1./ (1 + exp( 2* (d-(2*s-m))/s ) );
    % check exit condition and backup
    if norm(w-wt)/norm(w) < ratio, break; end
end
```

that I rewrote into python:

```
def baseline_arPLS(y, lam, ratio):
    # Estimate baseline with arPLS
    N = len(y)
    k = [numpy.ones(N), -2*numpy.ones(N-1), numpy.ones(N-2)]
    offset = [0, 1, 2]
    D = diags(k, offset).toarray()
    H = lam * numpy.matmul(D.T, D) 
    w_ = numpy.ones(N)
    while True:
        W = spdiags(w_, 0, N, N, format='csr')
        # Cholesky decomposition
        C = cholesky(W + H)
        z_ = spsolve(C.T, w_ * y)
        z = spsolve(C, z_)
        d = y - z 
        # make d- and get w^t with m and s 
        dn = d[d<0]
        m = numpy.mean(dn)
        s = numpy.std(dn)
        wt = 1. / (1 + numpy.exp(2 * (d - (2*s-m)) / s))
        # check exit condition and backup 
        norm_wt, norm_w = norm(w_-wt), norm(w_)
        if (norm_wt / norm_w) < ratio:
            break 
   
        w_ = wt
return(z)
```

Except for the input vector `y` the method requires parameters `lam` and `ratio` and it runs ok for values `lam<1.e+07` and `ratio>1.e-01`, but outputs poor results. When values are changed outside this range, for example `lam=1e+07`, `ratio=1e-02` the CPU starts heating up and job never finishes (I interrupted it after 1min). Also in both cases the following warning shows up:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py: 144: SparseEfficencyWarning: spsolve requires A to be CSC or CSR matrix format warn('spsolve requires A to be CSC or CSR format',
```

although I added the recommended `format='csr'` option to the `spdiags` call.

And here's some synthetic data (similar to one in the paper) for testing purposes. The noise was added along with a 3rd degree polynomial baseline The method works well for parameters `bl_1` and fails to converge for `bl_2`:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot
from scipy.sparse import spdiags, diags, identity
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
from numpy.linalg import cholesky, norm
import sys

x = numpy.arange(0, 1000)
noise = numpy.random.uniform(low=0, high = 10, size=len(x))
poly_3rd_degree = numpy.poly1d([1.2e-06, -1.23e-03, .36, -4.e-04])
poly_baseline = poly_3rd_degree(x)
y = 100 * numpy.exp(-((x-300)/15)**2)+\
        200 * numpy.exp(-((x-750)/30)**2)+ \
        100 * numpy.exp(-((x-800)/15)**2) + noise + poly_baseline


bl_1 = baseline_arPLS(y, 1e+07, 1e-01)
bl_2 = baseline_arPLS(y, 1e+07, 1e-02)

pyplot.figure(1)
pyplot.plot(x, y, 'C0')
pyplot.plot(x, poly_baseline, 'C1')
pyplot.plot(x, bl_1, 'k')

pyplot.show()
sys.exit(0)
```

All this is telling me that I'm doing something very non-optimal in my python implementation. Since I'm not knowledgeable enough about the intricacies of `scipy` computations I'm kindly asking for suggestions on how to achieve convergence in this calculations.

(I encountered an issue in running the "straight" matlab version of the code because the line `D = diff(speye(N), 2);` truncates the last two rows of the matrix, creating dimension mismatch later in the function. Following the description of matrix D's appearance I substituted this line by directly creating a tridiagonal matrix using the `diags` function.)

Comment: What did you do to debug this?  You don't show the full traceback, but I assume the problem is one of the `spsolve`, which take `C` or `C.T` as the argument.  What is `C` (not what you intend it to be, I want to know what it really is in the code, don't you?).  `W` may be the right format, but that doesn't means `C` is.  You have to make sure each step in your code works as intended!

Comment: I reread your question.  It's just a efficiency warning, so I shouldn't expect a traceback.  That fact that it works for some values, and not others makes it much harder to diagnose.  There isn't an actual code error.  I tried to run some of your code, but got a `NameError` on `y`.  If you want help, make sure the example case is complete, but also minimal - I don't need to run the plot stuff.

Comment: If you want help, the question needs to be clear and focused.  That warning stuff was a distraction.  You have a `while` loop that could run forever.  You have to determine if the problem is in one function that it calls, or loop itself.  How many times is it looping?  Is the stopping criteria realistic, etc and etc.

Comment: I edited the code to remove the ```NameError``` on ```y```. Also, the looping part was critical and your comment made me re-read the paper and realize that the authors, while mentioning setting an artificial limit for loop iterations, omitted to implement that in the matlab script. My understanding is that the method is actually not guaranteed to converge and the condition ```while True``` need to be replaced with an exit condition. I'm thankful for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Guided by the comment @hpaulj made, and suspecting that the loop exit wasn't coded properly, I re-visited the paper and found out that the authors actually implemented an exit condition that was not featured in their matlab script. Changing the `while` loop condition provides an exit for any set of parameters; my understanding is that algorithm is not guaranteed to converge in all cases, which is why this condition is necessary but was omitted by error. Here's the edited version of my python code:

```
def baseline_arPLS(y, lam, ratio):
    # Estimate baseline with arPLS
    N = len(y)
    k = [numpy.ones(N), -2*numpy.ones(N-1), numpy.ones(N-2)]
    offset = [0, 1, 2]
    D = diags(k, offset).toarray()
    H = lam * numpy.matmul(D.T, D) 
    w_ = numpy.ones(N)
    i = 0
    N_iterations = 100
    while i < N_iterations:
        W = spdiags(w_, 0, N, N, format='csr')
        # Cholesky decomposition
        C = cholesky(W + H)
        z_ = spsolve(C.T, w_ * y)
        z = spsolve(C, z_)
        d = y - z 
        # make d- and get w^t with m and s 
        dn = d[d<0]
        m = numpy.mean(dn)
        s = numpy.std(dn)
        wt = 1. / (1 + numpy.exp(2 * (d - (2*s-m)) / s))
        # check exit condition and backup 
        norm_wt, norm_w = norm(w_-wt), norm(w_)
        if (norm_wt / norm_w) < ratio:
            break 
   
        w_ = wt
        i += 1
return(z)
```